# How to get historical solana events?

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to get all the events emitted for a given smart contract, let's say Mango Markets(just an example): `4MangoMjqJ2firMokCjjGgoK8d4MXcrgL7XJaL3w6fVg`.

What I've tried (using python here, but idc if it's rust/ts/py):

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client, Pubkey
solana_client = Client("...")

res = solana_client.get_signatures_for_address(
    Pubkey.from_string('4MangoMjqJ2firMokCjjGgoK8d4MXcrgL7XJaL3w6fVg'),
    limit = 100
)

# Signature is 
# Signature(3ic5Ct26iif2V2PW9DcTf9ya1a2yPUUEn8khrR9oxorcPP2NpepKYopdQBQCVDDaKn4v1nJ2CACqzSJrrx7CX9RV)
solana_client.get_transaction(
    res.value[1].signature, 
    'jsonParsed', 
    max_supported_transaction_version=0
)
```

Which yields long output of transaction response. In this response, in `log_messages` there's line `"Program log: Instruction: PerpUpdateFunding"`. If I understand it correctly, this log is produced by this instruction: https://github.com/blockworks-foundation/mango-v4/blob/dev/programs/mango-v4/src/instructions/perp_update_funding.rs which calls function located in `src/state/perp_market.rs`: https://github.com/blockworks-foundation/mango-v4/blob/40f2842c105dacbcdcd15ed26fcdd5d526f27e0e/programs/mango-v4/src/state/perp_market.rs#L295. By the end of this function, the `PerpUpdateFundingLogV2` event is emitted, however I can't find it in the decoded transaction, neither I can find the data stored in its fields (`long_funding`, `stable_price` etc.).

So here are the questions: Where are emitted events stored? How do I get historical ones? Is there some indexer that can provide full history for given contract?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a hard concept of "events" on Solana, so the current method uses logs, as you've noticed.

The logs are stored on the transactions and blocks, so you're doing the right thing by reading them to find events. Otherwise, except by fetching snapshots and replaying transactions onto a `solana-ledger-tool`, it isn't possible to get historical snapshots of the data stored in the fields.

Your best bet might be to look through the `instructions` and `innerInstructions` of the transaction to see if you can get more information about what instruction was executed on the Mango program, and with what parameters.

There's a bit more information about the parsed transaction fields at https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction